# Use template matching for finding similar images Opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am truing to use the template matching in Opencv to find similar images. So far i got it working but I cannot figure out how to compare the images now.

My thinking was to use the cv2.matchTemplate and then use a threshold to check if any parts match and remove all that dont.
But when i look at the array that is produce the similar image has

```
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))
```

As the output.

A different image has

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

As the output which I though was perfect no matches so a empty array would be how to tell if they are different or the same. but then I used the same image as the template and this is what the output was

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

Which I though should be the same as the similar image.

My question is how can I determine what is similar and what is not?
Here is the code I am using right now.

```
def matcher(template, img, match_type, threshold):
    # Match operation
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, match_type)
    # store coordinates of matched areas
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
    return loc

locsame = matcher(template, same, cv2.TM_SQDIFF, 0.8)    
loc1 = matcher(template, sim, cv2.TM_SQDIFF, 0.8)
loc2 = matcher(template, di, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, 0.8)
```